# What happens when docker daemon runs out of network IP addresses to allocate when deploying compose environments?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

Currently, we are deploying a compose environment stack to an ubuntu server. In the compose file, we are not defining an address and utilizing the underlying default docker bridge network that docker compose comes with out of the box.

When we deploy our compose environment to a development server (IP range 10.x.x.x), the base `docker0` network address starts at `172.17.0.0`.

For every subsequent deployment, the address is incremented, (i.e. `172.18.0.0`, and then `172.19.0.0`) - this is expected.

My question is, what happens when the daemon runs out of addresses to allocate, does the process just start back over at `172.17.0.0`? Or does something else occur? I have been unable to find any of this information in the documentation.

Basically, I want to know if this is something I should be proactive about, rather than reactive when a problem occurs.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone coming across this in the future, it appears that while using the bridge network, the daemon picks a network from the default pool at random. There should be no issue, unless the networks are not cleaned up. For my particular case, the default network is being used with a default name. Therefore, the network gets replaced every time but under the same name - at this point, the prior network addresses are released as they are no longer being used.

Docker's Networking utils, `utils.go`:
https://github.com/docker/libnetwork/blob/a79d3687931697244b8e03485bf7b2042f8ec6b6/ipamutils/utils.go

A snippet from `utils.go` is included below:

```
var (
    // PredefinedLocalScopeDefaultNetworks contains a list of 31 IPv4 private networks with host size 16 and 12
    // (172.17-31.x.x/16, 192.168.x.x/20) which do not overlap with the networks in `PredefinedGlobalScopeDefaultNetworks`
    PredefinedLocalScopeDefaultNetworks []*net.IPNet
    // PredefinedGlobalScopeDefaultNetworks contains a list of 64K IPv4 private networks with host size 8
    // (10.x.x.x/24) which do not overlap with the networks in `PredefinedLocalScopeDefaultNetworks`
    PredefinedGlobalScopeDefaultNetworks []*net.IPNet
    mutex                                sync.Mutex
    localScopeDefaultNetworks            = []*NetworkToSplit{{"172.17.0.0/16", 16}, {"172.18.0.0/16", 16}, {"172.19.0.0/16", 16},
        {"172.20.0.0/14", 16}, {"172.24.0.0/14", 16}, {"172.28.0.0/14", 16},
        {"192.168.0.0/16", 20}}
    globalScopeDefaultNetworks = []*NetworkToSplit{{"10.0.0.0/8", 24}}
)
```

The default networks above are hard coded in, and it appears one of these is selected on every deployment.

Answer (score 3):

It will eventually spit out an error

> Error response from daemon: could not find an available, non-overlapping IPv4 address pool among the defaults to assign to the network

But, I had to run an experiment to trigger this; I've never hit this problem in the wild.

Here's the experiment:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
n=32
for i in $(seq "$n"); do
  docker network create "n$i" >/dev/null
done
for i in $(seq "$n"); do
  docker network inspect "n$i" --format '{{ .Name }}: {{ .IPAM.Config }}'
done
for i in $(seq "$n"); do
  docker network rm "n$i" >/dev/null
done
```

I am running this on Docker Desktop for Mac.  In the whale settings the default network address is 192.168.65.0/24.  It seems to allocate, in order:

1. The sixteen networks 172.16.0.0/16 through 172.31.0.0/16; then
2. The sixteen networks 192.168.0.0/20 through 192.168.224.0/20

When I actually ran it, it skipped 192.168.64.0/28 (which has the default network) but also 192.168.192.0/28 and 192.168.224.0/28; unclear why.  It did not skip 192.168.0.0/28 even though my host local network is 192.168.1.0/24.

It looks like [docker network create](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/) has an option to specify the `--subnet` in CIDR format, but there doesn't seem to be an option to specify the block size without also picking the specific address range.  You could create /20 networks in the 172.16.0.0/12 range to have more smaller networks, for example, but you'd have to allocate the IP ranges by hand.

---

In practice neither programs nor administrator cycles are free: there's a limit to how many containers you as an operator can fit on your local system and are able to manage.  For me running as many as four Docker Compose stacks at the same time is quite unusual, and the most complex Docker Compose network setups seem to use a default network plus two more; combining those is still only 12 networks together, when 20 or so will fit.

If you really do need to run or manage a lot of containers, a system like Kubernetes will make it easier to manage, but Kubernetes also comes with a different (and complex) networking system that doesn't run into this specific limitation.  If this is really your biggest concern, this is a place where there's a significant difference between the different container orchestrators

Comment: Thank you very much for doing this experiment and providing this analysis

I am curious how it went from allocating addresses from order 1. to order 2.

Why did it start using 192.168.0.0?, it is related to this point? "default network address is 192.168.65.0/24"